# I have some problem with my express module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, backend

My VS CODE doesn't see Javascript file. It's only TypeScript there because of which i can't require something. 
[Here's an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMy9j.png)

Comment: Have you executed the `npm install` in you project? if express is not listed in you `package.json`, you should `npm install express --save`

Comment: I did it first thing, of course.

Comment: Don't worry about the `ts`, it's just your linting engine. Can you show your project folder structure, as well?

Comment: All is okay, thanks all for the support. It was a Deno's problem. I had to turn it off.